# NSFileVersion's unresolvedConflictVersionsOfItemAtURL: behaviour

Tags: iphone, ios, version, icloud, uidocument

Does anybody know the case when [NSFileVersion unresolvedConflictVersionsOfItemAtURL:] returns more then 1 versions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

iCloud needs to keep track of all conflicts until your app explicitly resolves them.

In other words, [NSFileVersion unresolvedConflictVersionsOfItemAtURL:] returns a list of *unresolved* conflicts. It's possible a conflict occurred on Monday and your app didn't resolve it for some reason. Then another conflict happened on Tuesday. You will now have 3 versions :)